# interior of the set of positive operators

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $S$ be the set of all positive operators on $H$,$S$ is a closed cone in $B(H)$,the topology is induced by $\|\cdot\|$,is the interior $int(S)$ of $S$ empty?Suppose not,given a positive operator $T$,how to find $\delta > 0 $such that for all $U$ satisfying $\|U-T\|< \delta$,we have $U\in S$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any positive operator $T\in B(H)$ and $\varepsilon>0$, $T-\varepsilon iI$ is not positive.  Thus $S$ has empty interior, and the same argument shows that the collection of self-adjoint elements is not open.

Comment: You mean "$ T-\epsilon I$?

Comment: No, I meant $\varepsilon i$ times the identity operator